# Leaderboards - MySQL Order By Individual Sums

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table with the following columns:

```
+----+--------+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+
| Id | Member | End | Done | Right | Wrong | Score |
+----+--------+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

There are several entries for each Member.

I'd like to select some (twenty) rows ordered by the SUM() of each Member's Score.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM Challenge ORDER BY SUM(Score) LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to [GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm) member then you can `SUM` the score of each member. This query does what you want (sorted by the second field - the sum - in `DESC` order)

```
SELECT Member, SUM(Score) 
FROM Challenge 
GROUP BY Member
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: How could I also select some other values? Would it just be
SELECT Member, Right, SUM(Score) and then ORDER BY 3?

Comment: Exactly, or `SELECT SUM(Score), Member, etc, ... ORDERY BY 1 DESC`. But remember that every column that you want to `SELECT`, and is not int the GROUP BY, logically must to have in a aggregation function. e.g. SUM(Score), MAX(Done), some_sql_agg_func(field), etc.

Comment: Oh, I understand this now. Thanks a lot!